# Javascript regex that matches a decimal that is polluted with other characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the first set of digits in the following examples.

```
some stuff (6 out of 10 as a rating)
```

needs to return 6

```
some stuff (2.3 out of 10 as a rating)
```

needs to return 2.3

```
some stuff (10 out of 10 as a rating)
```

needs to return 10

Also, sometimes the string won't have a number

```
some stuff but nothing else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var match = /\d+(\.\d+)?/.exec("some stuff (10 out of 10 as a rating)");
alert(match[0]);
```

- `\d` matches any numner, 0-9
- `+` means 1 or more
- `\.` matches a .
- `?` means 0 or 1

so overall it means any number of digits (0-9) optionally followed by,  a decimal point followed by 1 or more digits.

As a function:

```
var getFirstNumber = function(input){
     var match = /\d+(\.\d+)?/.exec(input);
    return match[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `'some stuff (2.3 out of 10 as a rating)'.match(/\D*(\d\.?(\d)*)/)[1]`